# post editor with image upload

Tags: 7, media, nodes

I need a module or patch or something for a post editor that lets you upload images into the post

any help is appreciated.

Comment: which version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: im using drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module might be a good solution to this, depending on your needs. It is still under development and still has a few issues, but it's probably stable enough to us (we are using it on several production sites without any problems). I think this module has the best approach to the problem of embedding images within node content.